# Error: Conflicting types for function (C)

Tags: c, function, types, floating-point

So I'm making a function that makes a table, that puts the x and y values through an equation. this is what I have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(){
    int x, y;
    float num;

    printf("%3c", '+');
    for (x=5; x <= 100;x=x+5){
        printf("%8i",x);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (y = 5; y<= 100;y=y+5){
        printf("%3d ",y);
        for (x=5;x<=100;x=x+5){
            num = theMath(x, y);    
            printf("%7f", num);
            printf(" ");    
        }
        printf("\n");

    }
    return 0;
}

float theMath(int x, int y){
    float sum;
    sum = ((x*x*x*x)/(y*y)) + sqrt(y);
    return sum;
}
```

It's telling me "Error: Conflicting types for 'theMath'", and I can't figure out why. Compiling with gcc.

Comment: How are you compiling this?

Comment: I'm compiling with gcc

Comment: Can you paste the gcc line (i.e. `gcc test.c -lm -o test.o`) ?

Comment: gcc xtable.c -o xtable -lm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a prototype definition(function declaration) of theMath before its function call. That should be the reason for the error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

//add declaration of the function here
float theMath(int x, int y);
int main(){
  int x, y;
  float num;

  printf("%3c", '+');
  for (x=5; x <= 100;x=x+5){
    printf("%8i",x);
  }
  printf("\n");
  for (y = 5; y<= 100;y=y+5){
    printf("%3d ",y);
    for (x=5;x<=100;x=x+5){
      num = theMath(x, y);  
      printf("%7f", num);
      printf(" ");  
    }
    printf("\n");

  }
  return 0;
}

float theMath(int x, int y){
  float sum;
  sum = ((x*x*x*x)/(y*y)) + sqrt(y);
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Not my downvote. However, there **is** a _definition_. He actually should add a _prototype_ _declaration_. Please do not confuse these two terms! Or just move the definiton before using the function.

Comment: No, this is no "prototype definition" (that would be a _definition_ with a prototype-style signature, the standard if you do not use an extra declaration, but just define (which implies declaration) the function before its usage.

Comment: Anyway ,this is a dup.

Answer (score 0):

Your function *theMath* is used before being defined, and it is not declared before usage. You just have to declare the function at the beginning of your C file:

```
   float theMath(int x, int y);
```